# export symbols from IDA pro for use in GDB

Tags: gdb, mach-o, ida

I have a dylib file a2.dylib I disassembled in IDA pro which is stripped of symbols. I have used a1.dylib which has symbols albeit older version of a2.dylib with Bindiff to diff out function names to match a2.dylib. I need these derived function names to be exported for use in debugging a2.dylib inside GDB; something like a equivalent of a windows PDB file for use inside GDB. How could I go about doing it in IDA pro 6.4? thanks.

Comment: No idea, but if libraries are different version, symbols (addresses) will be wrong, and I don't think there is much use of that.

Comment: Why not just debug it in IDA?

Comment: Hi Igor, can IDA pro debug a live jailbroken iOS binary using GDB?

Comment: Not iOS at the moment, but OS X debugging definitely works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a symbol table with [SymTabCreator](https://github.com/karstenBriksoft/SymTabCreator). All you need is a list of address ↔ symbol mapping.

Note that the README says it works for main executables only, so you may need to adjust the [imageBase](https://github.com/karstenBriksoft/SymTabCreator/blob/281b1687d7bfbad6e01b1dc211cd4ad398a65e47/SymTabCreator.m#L91) offset for a dylib.

Comment: Thanks. Is this similar to rebasing the lib binary?